# android admob shown different ad

Tags: android, admob

I am doing an example app with admob for learning purpose. I refer to [***this***](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/admob-manager/) website and created a project with same package name and same publisher_id as in that site. I run the app it shows the ad but different from the site. So that I created an account in admob (not real data and test mode) with my own package name. I have used my account's publisher_id and package name. But in the both the cases I got same ad. I run the app from emulator sdk 4.0.

This is what I got:

[image]

How to display some different ads instead of the above ad? Please help me.

Comment: Because that site said `request.setTesting(true);`, it will always serve test ads to emulators (devices will still get real ads).  If you remove that command, you can test getting live ads on the emulator.  By the way, that website is using an old version of the SDK.  I would recommend [downloading](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download) the latest SDK version and using the corresponding official documentation to integrate with AdMob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is defined as testdevice, means that only testAds (like the Ad you see) get displayed.

Comment: Thanks, How can i add different ad in my admob account for real time apps. please help me.

Comment: you need not add any Ad.. the Ad will automatically comes from admob server... but you can control the type of Ad to be displayed in your app.. go through the admob site FAQ and one more thing  is you remove the testmode you can see the real Ads

Comment: i did the following things: Disable test mode for all requests - enabled Use Google ads and Google certified ad networks to improve fill rate. - enabled. i use my publish_id,package which mentioned in the account. Is correct? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Admob will be pushing the ads automatically. All you have to do is making sure that you didn't mark the app as testing.

Comment: i did the following things:
 Disable test mode for all requests - enabled
 Use Google ads and Google certified ad networks to improve fill rate. - enabled.

i use my publish_id,package which mentioned in the account.

Is correct? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal result. If you see this sample ad, real ads will be shown on a real device. Just run your app with a real device to see the real ads.